# Implementation of logging in a node.js app

Tags: node.js, logging

Practically, I use use [Let's Chat](https://github.com/sdelements/lets-chat) and I'd like to store connections like the Apache's log file (date, IP address, browser, ...) in a logrotated file.
I found those projects :

- Log4js-node
- Caterpillar
- Winston

But they are focusing on system/debug log and/or I don't know how to implement them in my case.

All ideas are welcome, thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For HTTP request logger there is morgan: https://www.npmjs.com/package/morgan

Example from docs:

```
var express = require('express')
var fs = require('fs')
var morgan = require('morgan')

var app = express()

// create a write stream (in append mode) 
var accessLogStream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/access.log', {flags: 'a'})

// setup the logger 
app.use(morgan('combined', {stream: accessLogStream}))

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
  res.send('hello, world!')
})
```

You can combine morgan with for example winston:

```
var logger = new winston.Logger({
...
}),

logger.stream = {
    write: function(message, encoding){
        logger.info(message);
    }
};

app.use(require("morgan")("combined", { "stream": logger.stream }));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need web server like logging you should use Morgan with Express, just include it and use it as:

```
var express = require('express');
var morgan = require('morgan');

var app = express();
app.use(morgan('combined'));
```

https://github.com/expressjs/morgan